# Android: listview has a strange width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

In my app I'm creating a Listview inside a RelativeLayout at the centre of the screen. This RelativeLayout is in the centre of the screen end inside there is an ImageView ad background and the ListView.

This is the result that I want to obtain:

[image]

and this is the result that I obtain:

[image]

The red color is the background color of ListView, so you can see its size.

My activity xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#70000000"
    tools:context="com.example.example.RecordActivity">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_record"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:background="#70000000">

        </ListView>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my adapter layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="row"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

what's wrong? How can I obtain the result in first picture?

Thanks

Comment: layout_centerInParent doesnt work for LinearLayouts, not that that is the direct cause of your problem. Set your RelativeLayout - content_record width to match_parent. Actually, looking at this a good bit of cleaning up can be done

Comment: are you changing alignment of listview dynamically?, because `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` should center it in your screen as it is doing to `imageview`.

Comment: Thing is even making listview's `width` to `wrap_content`, listview will still cover whole screen width. In your case it is in center of parent and it is making its width to full screen. you need to give custom width to listview for making it specific area.

Comment: Can I assign it the parameters of RelativeLayout content_record no?

Answer (score 1):

change your activity xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#70000000"
    tools:context="com.example.example.RecordActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_record"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_record"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="#70000000">

    </ListView>


</FrameLayout>
```

or remove the imageView and set the background of listView to

```
android:background="@drawable/back_record"
```

Comment: with this code I have a background of listview in the left of screen and the listview il full screen in width

Answer (score 0):

Change height and width of `content_record` `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` to show in full screen.

**EDIT::** **Give Specific width to listview**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#70000000"
        tools:context="com.example.example.RecordActivity">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_record"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background:"@drawable/back_record">



            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="750dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:background="#70000000">

            </ListView>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want show listview in full screen but inside RelativeLayout "content_record"

Comment: you should give background to inner `relativelayout` rather using `imageview` as a background.

Comment: I tried... I have a full screen listview with a background "back_record" in full screen...

Comment: sorry!! i forget to change `width` and `height` to `wrap_content` of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: no there is yet an error, the listview fill the screen in width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66759/discussion-between-dhaval-gondaliya-and-nazz-areno).

Comment: making listview's width to `wrap_content` will also cover full screen width. you need to change width for particular size.

Comment: mmm so, should I change listview width only programmatically? and not with xml code?

Comment: better change it in xml so you can know how much width should be.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to clean it up some

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_record"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#70000000"
    tools:context="com.example.example.RecordActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/back_record" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A background of #700000000 seems a bit odd, is there a reason for it? And is it the background for everything in your app? If so, `you might consider setting your app theme's background to @color/main_background and adding a color xml of <color name="main_background">#70000000</color>`.

Comment: with your last update the backgroud is stretch and fill all screen in width size...

Comment: @nazz_areno I haven't tested it. I'll look when I get to work. Wait, remove the imageview from your list item layout then do what I have